# can't find where to create adwords developer token

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm truing to figure out how to create an adwords developer token in new google interface. It was in settings tab formerly (right here at the screenshot http://take.ms/9lBlZ) but now it's gone. I looked through almost all links and didn't find an answer. So I really appreciate your help guys! Thanks!

Comment: I too have created a test MCC account and all the instructions say to go to settings -> account settings, and then there will be a option called Adwords API Center in the left menu, but that option is not anywhere in MCC for me. It's a new test account, verified via email and text message, it's incredibly frustrating. I'm hoping it's just a matter of waiting for some background check to happen.

Comment: Hi, Alex did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

If you create a campaign in your MCC (manager account), the MCC became normal Account, and you cant find "AdWords API Center" option.

I had to re-create another MCC

Comment: This should be documented.

Answer (score 2):

This thread is kind of old, but I just went through this so I can highlight the things that were confusing to me.

You need to create a legitimate MCC account, AND a test account.  In the real one you need to apply for a developer token.  You want to put this token in the properties file here api.adwords.developerToken

From your test MCC you need to create a test client. Use the clientId from the TEST client you just created in api.adwords.clientCustomerId in the properties file.

You need to get an API token for your app (and an OAuth token) through Google's developer console https://console.developers.google.com

Make sure the active google account session for your browser is for the email you registered your TEST Account to.  Run the script they give to get the refresh token and put it here api.adwords.refreshToken in the properties file.

Now you're using your test developer token from your real account and given permissions to use the test account.

Google made this way more confusing than it had to be in my opinion...hopefully this helps someone figure it out though!

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of Adwords Manager accounts, normal and testing.

[How to get a testing account](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/accounts-overview#test_accounts)

With the normal one, I got the developer token but I cannot run nothing throught the API because the account was not approved.

So I created a testing account, which allows to work with the API without the need of being approved.

With the testing account I didn't saw the Adwords API Center link under Account Settings.

Reading documentation I saw **the developer token of a normal account can be used with a different Adwords account**.

So I'm using the info (client_id, client_secret, oauth_token) of a testing Adwords account and the developer token a normal Adwords account.

To get the Oauth_token you can use the OAuth Playground (remember to set the Playground link for redirection on your Oauth credentials).

[Instructions to get a OAuth Playground with Adwords](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/authentication#oauth2_playground)

Comment: Thanks I have spent so long trying to figure this out, the developer token of a normal account can be used with a different Adwords account. was the key thats not clear, it makes it sound like you create a test account and get different keys for this account not that you can use the keys from your live account.

Answer (score 0):

Please complete the billing details after creating MCC account.

Once that is completed you can see API Center option under Tool Icon.

By filling billing details doesn't charge you but its just for verification purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue.

Go here: https://ads.google.com/home/tools/manager-accounts/

Click "Create a manager account", follow the prompts and voila.